# Cannot find Realm module "(...)node_modules\Realm\build\Release\realm.node"

Tags: node.js, realm

I'm trying to create node server using Realm. I have installed Realm like the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/install/) say:
`npm install realm`. The module is visible in `node_modules` folder and `package.json`.

I try to import Realm like the docs say too:

`const Realm = require("realm");`

But this import throws an error (it's in my language, so translation of the error message might be not word-to-word):

```
Error: cannot find module:
    \\?\D:\GIT\nuxt-test\node_modules\realm\build\Release\realm.node
        at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:18)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at bindings (D:\GIT\nuxt-test\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
        at getRealmConstructor (D:\GIT\nuxt-test\node_modules\realm\lib\index.js:37:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GIT\nuxt-test\node_modules\realm\lib\index.js:62:26)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
```

Additional info:

OS - Windows 7

Node version: 16.4 (upgraded from 10.15.3 trying to solve this)

What might be wrong with my import?

EDIT:
I have noticed that on installation of Realm npm throws some warnings:

```
realm@10.5.0 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.60 but none is installed.
 deprecated-react-native-listview@0.0.6 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed.
```

which is surprising as I'm not using `react-native` SDK, but the `node` one.

I tried to install `realm-web` package and it seems to function properly (!) even though I run it from `node`. But I don't know if this is an acceptable solution as docs say the `realm-web` package is not intended for `node`.

Comment: Details are important. What's your coding platform (that should be a tag). What versions of Node.js and the OS is installed? Did you create a projects per the docs?

Comment: What do you mean by coding platform? This is a local project on my PC with Windows 7. I created the projects using `npx create-nuxt-app`, as this is supposed to be part of nuxt app. I didn't mention nuxt, as I didn't think it was relevant. Node version is 10.15.3.

Comment: Coding platform is what you use to write code and knowing that helps to narrow the question to people that can more likely help. For example, if your coding on Windows in C#, a Swift Developer on macOS will probably not be able to help as much. Tagging the question correctly exposes the question to the more correct crowd.

Comment: You're right, I am trying to tag questions properly, but I just didn't think about node in the context of this one. I did upgrade my node to v. 16.4, as you brought my attention to the fact that I'm using old one, but unfortunatelly it didn't help and the problem persists.